# Access violation writing location 0x61d1e5bc

Tags: c

I declared `H` from `TwoDimArray` function for a 2D dynamic array. when line (mark as `**`) executed, the compiler shows that error:
`Access violation writing location 0x61d1e5bc.`

with small lenA & lenB values (such as 250), there isn't any problem!

```
int lenA=100030;
int lenB=100030;
int **H;

int TwoDimArray(int ***x,int nRow,int nCol)
{
    int i;
    *x=(int **)malloc(nRow*sizeof(int *));
    if(*x==NULL)
        return 1;
    (*x)[0]=(int *)malloc(nCol*nRow*sizeof(int));
    if((*x)[0]==NULL)
        return 2;
    for(i=1;i<nRow;i++)
        (*x)[i]=(*x)[i-1]+nCol;
    return 0;
}

    TwoDimArray(&H, lenB, lenA);

    for(int j=0;j<lenA;j++){
       H[0][j]=0;
    }

**  for(int i=0;i<lenB;i++){
       H[i][0]=0;
}
```

Comment: The **compiler** shows that error?

Comment: Where is `H`? Show us.

Comment: `int ***x` Ah triple-star programming, shiny!

Comment: @Haroogan: I edited post, H is `int **H`

Comment: It's ridiculous code...

Comment: @trojanfoe: I use this function for declare 2d dynamic arrays. what suggestions do you for this action?

Comment: @milad_b: `vector<vector<int>>` for example.

Comment: I would suggest returning `int **` and checking for `malloc()` failure (which means calling `free()` upon failure) and return those status codes via an `int &`.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this error is emitted by the compiler, rather than the program actually being run?

Comment: Too localized. It is unlikely that any future visitor to the site will have an access violation writing to 0x61d1e5bc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `100030`x`100030` array of 32-bit ints requires 40GB of RAM. Does your process have access to this much memory?

In all probability, the second `malloc` is failing. However, your code ignores the failure and carries on regardless.